# R: Changing order of guide/legend from sorting strings to sorting numeric in ggplot2

Tags: r, string, sorting, ggplot2, numeric

I am trying to create an isoline plot with ggplot2. I successfully filled the tiles of the geom_tile() function in groups using the cut() function for breaks. Using this approach, the breaks will be interpreted as strings though, not as values, giving me trouble in the order the guide is set up. This way, e.g. a value of 20 will be interpreted as a bigger number than 180, resulting in fatally misleading colors in the plot, such as this purposely ugly one:
[image: Isoline plot]

To create this ugly image, I used the following code:

```
plot.isoline <- function(data, dbr=20, n_interp=200){

  library(akima)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(fields)

  data <- read.table(file = "http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=90687695741432763217&t=9068769574143276321730276", header = T)

  dint <- interp(x = data$x, y = data$y, z = data$z,
                 xo = seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), length = n_interp),
                 yo = seq(min(data$y), max(data$y), length = n_interp))

  dat_interp <- data.frame(expand.grid(x=dint$x,y=dint$y), z=c(dint$z))

  br <- seq(floor(min(dat_interp$z)/dbr)*dbr, ceiling(max(dat_interp$z)/dbr)*dbr, dbr)

  breaks <- cut(dat_interp$z, breaks = br)
  breaks <- gsub(","," - ",breaks,fixed=TRUE)

  dat_interp$breaks <- sapply(breaks, function(x){strsplit(x, "[( ]")[[1]][[2]]})

  ret <- ggplot(dat_interp) + 
    aes(x=x, y=y, z=z) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill=breaks)) +
    scale_fill_manual("TEMP", values=tim.colors(length(br)), guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
    stat_contour(breaks=br) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))

  return(ret)        
}
```

I already tried setting the break strings to values the following way:

```
dat_interp$breaks <- as.numeric(sapply(breaks, function(x){strsplit(x, "[( ]")[[1]][[2]]}))
```

This approach only leads to an error "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale". I am sure there has to be a way to order the scale in a numeric way, and I'd be really glad if someone could help me out on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the helpful input of @krlmlr I managed to solve the problem. As he said, the crucial part was to just edit the levels(). For anyone interested, this is the important part:

```
  breaks <- cut(dat_interp$z, breaks = br)
  levels(breaks) <- gsub(","," - ", levels(breaks),fixed=TRUE)
  dat_interp$breaks <- breaks
  levels(dat_interp$breaks) <- as.numeric(sapply(levels(breaks), function(x){strsplit(x, "[( ]")[[1]][[2]]}))
```

This way I get the following result, properly sorted:
[image: Working result]

And the full code:

```
plot.isoline <- function(data, dbr=20, n_interp=200){

  library(akima)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(fields)

  data <- read.table(file = "http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=90687695741432763217&t=9068769574143276321730276", header = T)

  dint <- interp(x = data$x, y = data$y, z = data$z,
                 xo = seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), length = n_interp),
                 yo = seq(min(data$y), max(data$y), length = n_interp))

  dat_interp <- data.frame(expand.grid(x=dint$x,y=dint$y), z=c(dint$z))

  br <- seq(floor(min(dat_interp$z)/dbr)*dbr, ceiling(max(dat_interp$z)/dbr)*dbr, dbr)

  breaks <- cut(dat_interp$z, breaks = br)
  levels(breaks) <- gsub(","," - ", levels(breaks),fixed=TRUE)
  dat_interp$breaks <- breaks
  levels(dat_interp$breaks) <- as.numeric(sapply(levels(breaks), function(x){strsplit(x, "[( ]")[[1]][[2]]}))

  ret <- ggplot(dat_interp) + 
    aes(x=x, y=y, z=z) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill=breaks)) +
    scale_fill_manual("TEMP", values=tim.colors(length(br)), guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
    stat_contour(breaks=br) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))

  return(ret)        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot2` will sort `character` values as strings, and `factor` values by their level. In your code,

```
breaks <- gsub(","," - ",breaks,fixed=TRUE)
```

converts the factor returned by `cut` to a character. Try omitting it.

If you need to change the display, use something like

```
levels(breaks) <- gsub(",", " - ", levels(breaks), fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: But after using

`dat_interp$breaks <- sapply(breaks, function(x){strsplit(x, "[( ]")[[1]][[2]]})`

there are no levels attached anymore, right? If I convert those strings to values using as.numeric(), there is still this error message (Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale)

Comment: @oepix: Oh, I missed that line. Try to use the breaks returned by `cut` in your `dat_interp` data frame, and modify only the levels if necessary. (I think the `strsplit` can be implemented using `gsub`, too.)

Comment: Okay, this helped me figure it out, thank you so much @krlmlr!