# How to sort the index legend by number and not by string in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code:

```
 gg = ggplot() +  geom_line(data = correctAnswersPerStimu_1010v1, size=1,
                            aes(x=as.character(testPhase), y=percent_correct, group=as.character(individualIndex), colour = as.character(individualIndex)))
  
  
  gg = gg + geom_point(data = correctAnswersPerStimu_1010v1, aes(x=as.character(testPhase), y=percent_correct),
                       shape = 23, size = 3, color="black", stroke = 1)
  
  gg = gg + labs(title=paste("Experiment 1010 stimuli correct answers % per phase", sep = ""),
                 x ="Phase", y = "% Correct", fill="Phase")
  
  gg = gg + guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Index")) + ylim(0, 100)

  gg
```

Thanks generate this graph:
[image]

What do I have to change in the ggplot to show the legend sorted by index (0,1,2,3,... 14,15) and not by string (0,1,10,11,...)?

Comment: Try using `factor()` instead of `as.character()`.

Comment: Please go through this links [Sorting legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725079/r-changing-order-of-guide-legend-from-sorting-strings-to-sorting-numeric-in-ggp) or [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776247/ggplot-doesnt-sort-values-like-it-supposed-to)